# Authorized HttpClient for Google Drive SDK v3

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I've exported a few Google Docs as html using the following code.

```
DriveService service = ...
var stream = service.Files.Export(gdoc.DocID, "text/html").ExecuteAsStream();
```

Then I tried to download the images linked within that document which failed with permission errors.
The image urls works in the browser where I'm logged in but not from my program.

In v2 I believe I could do

```
DriveService service = ...
var stream = service.HttpClient.Download...
```

But in v3 HttpClient only exposes a few configurations.

How can I download the embedded images in the downloaded html?

Answer (score 0):

I began by adding back the Google Drive SDK v2 but realized that it was the exact same class for service.HttpClient.

This was the hint that helped me.

[image]

When developing in dotnet-core I had to add a dependency to `System.Net.Http` in
`project.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0",
```

After which service.HttpClient.Get... was available.